# customizing flash.display.textfield class (source)

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

Is the source code available somewhere just to make a few small fixes to textfield class?

Comment: I always assumed that core flash classes are implemented as native objects and thus have no actionscript source, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, the sources for the internal flash.* classes are not available. To modify or add behavior you'll need to subclass TextField.

Comment: alwaysShowSelection:Boolean  [read-write] 
When set to true and the text field is not in focus, Flash Player highlights the selection in the text field in gray. 


How can I change gray to another color by subclassing?

Answer (score 1):

You should extend the Textfield class. Override what you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Flex is an open-source SDK built on top of Flash, so it shouldn't be a problem to find the relevant source file in the SDK and apply your fix.

But it might be simpler to either:

1. Apply the fix externally. e.g. by deriving from the class and overriding.
2. Open a bug with the SDK people and ask them to fix it (that is, if it's not an urgent critical bug).

If you do end up fixing it in the SDK, consider releasing your fix back to the community.

Comment: The TextField class isn't accessible as part of the Flex SDK as it's in the flash package.  I'm not sure it's possible to retrieve the source for TextField